# Parameterization in UIAutomator/Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, parameterized, android-uiautomator, spoon

I am using Android-UiAutomator / Espresso for automating Android app. For web automation i used selenium and for data parameterization used excel sheet and used Apache POI jars to read data.

i just want to know is there any way we can use the excel sheet or can implement data parameterization in Android-UiAutomator/ Espresso ? Right now i am using Spoon framework for reports and execution. Is there any feasibility in spoon framework for this feature.

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an out-of-the-box solution to import data from excel, but you *can* create parameterized tests using JUnit4.

The [Parameterized](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) runner allows you to do this. For example:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyParameterizedTest {

    @Parameter
    public String mTextToFind;

    private UiDevice mDevice;

    @Parameters
    public static Iterable<? extends Object> data() {
        return Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Instrumentation instr = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
        mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(instr);
    }

    @Test
    public void testHasText() {
        // Make sure the text is on the screen
        Assert.assertTrue(mDevice.hasObject(By.text(mTextToFind));
    }
}
```

Comment: i have some 100 records of data in excel. can i do this concept